# How many different ways are possible

Tags: combinatorics

Twenty students, including John, Casey and Michelle, are candidates to serve on a
committee of six.

(a) How many different ways of committees are possible if contain three of them?

My attempt(Not sure it is correct)
20C3 - 6C3 = 1120

(b) How many different ways of committees are possible if contain at least one of them?

My attempt(Not sure it is correct)
20C3 - 6C1 = 1134

Please help to check if it's correct, thanks alot...

Comment: For the first...you know three members of your committee, all you have to do is to choose $3$ more from the remaining $17$.

Comment: Can you explain where your formulas come from?  It isn't clear to me how you are thinking about this.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints.

For part (a), you know three of the members will be John, Casey, and Michelle.  So how many ways can you choose the other three people from the remaining $17$?

For part (b), one way to do this is to calculate the number of all possible committees, and then subtract out those committees that *do not* have John, Casey, or Michelle.  What remains will have *at least one* of them.

How many total possible committees are there?  How many committees don't have John, Casey, or Michelle?